# integral of $(x^2)^n$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I tried two methods of doing this,

a. $\int(x^2)^ndx = \int{x^{2n}}dx = \frac {x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}+C$

b. $\int(x^2)^ndx = \frac{({x^2})^{n+1}}{(n+1)(2x)}+C = \frac {x^{2n+1}}{2n+2}+C$

why is it different?

Comment: The second method is flawed. While it is the case that $\int f(g(x))g'(x)\,dx = F(g(x))$ if $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, it is not the case that $\int f(g(x))\,dx = F(g(x))/g'(x)$, as you have just shown. (If that latter formula were valid, why would we ever use substitution?)

Comment: @GregMartin, maybe your comment is better placed as an answer, very well explained by the way.